# Countability of uncountable discrete spaces

Tags: general-topology

I know that there are countable topological spaces with the discrete topology, which are not second countable. But I cannot find an argument, why uncountable spaces with the discrete topology should be second countable.

Answer (score 3):

If a set $X$ is given the discrete topology, then there is a unique smallest (according to the $\subseteq$ relation) base: $\mathcal{B} = \{ \{ x \} : x \in X \}$. This means that the smallest cardinality of a base for discrete topology on $X$ is $|X|$. This then implies that

1. If $X$ is countable (as a set), then the discrete topology on $X$ is second-countable.
2. If $X$ is uncountable (as a set), then the discrete topology on $X$ is not second-countable.

There are countable topological spaces which are not second countable (the [Arens-Fort space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arens%E2%80%93Fort_space) is one example), And there are uncountable topological spaces which are second-countable (the usual real  line is one example). But for discrete spaces, whether or not they are second-countable is entirely dependent on the cardinality of the underlying set.

Comment: What is the proof of your first statement, namely that there exists a unique smallest base?

Comment: @PhilippWeder Essentially by construction. Every base for a discrete topology must include all singleton sets (since for each $x \in X$ the set $\{ x \}$ is an open neighborhood of $x$, and so if $\mathcal{D}$ is any base for $X$, then there is a $U \in \mathcal{D}$ with $x \in U \subseteq \{ x \}$, which implies $U = \{ x \} \in \mathcal{D}$), and the family of all singleton sets is a base for the topology. Therefore the family of all singleton sets is the smallest (according to the $\subseteq$ relation) base for the discrete topology on $X$.